# QRubberBand, how to draw on it

Tags: c++, qt, draw, rubber, qrubberband

I'm trying to draw numbers on `QRubberBand` object. I have class widget with `QRubberBand` object `rectangleRubberBand`;

I can show this area etc, but I'm trying to draw on area **not** on the widget some  numbers, for example width and height of this area. How can I do this? It's for measure purpose of charts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not drawing on rubber band but it does what you need :

```
void MyButton::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    rubberBand->setGeometry(QRect(mypoint, event->pos()).normalized());//Area Bounding
    QToolTip::showText( event->globalPos(), QString("%1,%2")
                                             .arg(rubberBand->size().width())
                                             .arg(rubberBand->size().height()),this );
}
```

`QToolTip` is shown near the cursor. It dynamically changes and shows actual information about size of rubber band.

Result (black area is a cursor) :

[image]

Harder solution: subclass `QRubberBand` and reimplement `paintEvent`. For example:

Header :

```
#ifndef RUBBERBAND_H
#define RUBBERBAND_H

#include <QRubberBand>
#include <QPaintEvent>

class RubberBand : public QRubberBand
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit RubberBand(Shape s, QWidget * p = 0);


signals:

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event);

public slots:

};

#endif // RUBBERBAND_H
```

cpp :

```
#include "rubberband.h"
#include <QPainter>
RubberBand::RubberBand(QRubberBand::Shape s, QWidget *p) :
    QRubberBand(s,p)
{
}

void RubberBand::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QRubberBand::paintEvent(event);
    QPainter p(this);
    p.setPen(QPen(Qt::black,2));
    if(size().width() >10 && size().height() >10)
    {
        p.drawText(20,20,QString("%1,%2").arg(size().width()).arg(size().height()));
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Choose the best approach for you.

Comment: there is any chance to see this numbers in the right middle of rubberband? not bottom right?

Comment: @Shepherd instead of 20,20 use center of rubber band for example, it is simple drawing, you can draw this text anywhere on widget.